# Asp.NET MVC & Entity Framework - Error when generating Controller using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm trying to add a controller in my ASP.NET MVC project.

I am using Entity Framework Code First (6.0), and when I right-click the Controllers folder in my project and selecting Add Controller with views using Entity Framework

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0M1s.png]

And I am getting this error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpA0Z.png]

This is my `RequetesContext` class :

```
public class RequetesContext : IdentityDbContext<Utilisateur>
{
public RequetesContext ()
    : base()
{
}

public DbSet<Agriculteur> Agriculteurs { get; set; }
public DbSet<DirectionRegionnale> DirectionsRegionnales { get; set; }
public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
public DbSet<EtatAvancement> EtatAvancements { get; set; }
public DbSet<TypeDeRequete> TypesDeRequetes { get; set; }
public DbSet<DirectionDesMetiers> DirectionsDesMetiers { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DirectionDesMetiers>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Agriculteur)
        .WithRequired(e => e.DirectionDesMetiers)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdDirectionDesMetiers)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<DirectionDesMetiers>()
        .HasMany(e => e.DirectionRegionnale)
        .WithRequired(e => e.DirectionDesMetiers)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdDirectionDesMetiers)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<EtatAvancement>()
       .HasMany(e => e.Agriculteur)
       .WithRequired(e => e.EtatAvancement)
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdEtat)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<EtatAvancement>()
        .HasMany(e => e.DirectionRegionnale)
        .WithRequired(e => e.EtatAvancement)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdEtat)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
       .HasMany(e => e.Agriculteur)
       .WithRequired(e => e.Region)
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdRegion)
       .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
        .HasMany(e => e.DirectionRegionnale)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Region)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdRegion)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TypeDeRequete>()
      .HasMany(e => e.Agriculteur)
      .WithRequired(e => e.TypeDeRequete)
      .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdTypeDeRequete)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TypeDeRequete>()
        .HasMany(e => e.DirectionRegionnale)
        .WithRequired(e => e.TypeDeRequete)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdTypeDeRequete)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Agriculteur)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Utilisateur)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdUtilisateur)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Utilisateur>()
        .HasMany(e => e.DirectionRegionnale)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Utilisateur)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.IdUtilisateur)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

and this is my `Agriculteur` model class:

```
public class Agriculteur
{
    [Key]
    public int IdAgriculteur { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CIN")]
    public string CinAgriculteur { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nom agriculteur")]
    public string NomAgriculteur { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Prénom agriculteur")]
    public string PrenomAgriculteur { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type requête")]
    public int IdTypeDeRequete { get; set; }
    public virtual TypeDeRequete TypeDeRequete { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Etat")]
    public int IdEtat { get; set; }
    public virtual EtatAvancement EtatAvancement { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Direction des métiers")]
    public int IdDirectionDesMetiers { get; set; }
    public virtual DirectionDesMetiers DirectionDesMetiers { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Région")]
    public int IdRegion { get; set; }
    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Objet requête")]
    public string Objet { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date arrivée")]
    public DateTime? DateArrivee { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Cloture")]
    public DateTime? DateCloture { get; set; }

    public string IdUtilisateur { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdUtilisateur")]
    public virtual Utilisateur Utilisateur { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Utilisateur Class :

```
public class Utilisateur : IdentityUser
{
    public string Nom { get; set; }
    public string Prenom { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Agriculteur> Agriculteur { get; set; }
  
}
```

For more information I am using

- Entity Framework version 6.0.0.0
- Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework version 2.0.0.0
- Microsoft.Owin version 3.0.1.0

Please Help me !

Comment: Can you translate the error to English?

Comment: as this is your first post some guidence on the proper way to do this, firstly read here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, you need to be much clearer about what you want and errors should be provided in text not as images, this allows searches to pick up your question this means both other people with the same issue and with the solution can find your question

Comment: thank you for your answer, and here the error, "A error occurred during the execution of the Selected Code Generator, 'Exception has been thrown by the target of a call ' "